# How do I check connection of data (before deleting it) with other tables

Tags: mysql

I work with users roles in my db - roles has permissions.
I other words I have roles - permissions connection. If I delete something another will be useless. 
How do I write DELETE query in MySQL, which also checking value from another table. If this value existing raise error , if not deleting it.

```
Here is my schema:

    TABLE role ( 
       id , 
       name varchar(255) , 
       UNIQUE (name), 
        # name of role PRIMARY KEY(id) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

    TABLE role_permission ( 
       id, 
       role_id, 
       permission_id, 
       PRIMARY KEY(id) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

    TABLE permission ( 
       id int(10) , 
       action enum('GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE' ) NOT NULL, 
       modifier enum('Any', 'Own', 'None') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None', 
       resource_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
       PRIMARY KEY(id) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resource` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `resource_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, # name of resource
  UNIQUE (`resource_name`),
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You can use InnoDB constraints to foreign keys.

Comment: I'm so sorry but, I am noobie in SQL.
I have many to many relation. I should take values from role_permission table?

Comment: Shoe your table structures.

Comment: TABLE  `role` (
  `id` ,
  `name` varchar(255) ,
  UNIQUE (name),            # name of role
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

TABLE  `role_permission` (
  `id`,
  `role_id`,
  `permission_id`,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
TABLE  `permission` (
  `id` int(10) ,
  `action` enum('GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE' ) NOT NULL,
  `modifier` enum('Any', 'Own', 'None') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
  `resource_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Nice. Almost there. What columns have role_permission?

Comment: In comment above I have written this

Comment: Your schema is not complete. `resource_id` comes from where? I guess there is some table `resources` it is important for your case. and provide schema and data sample even for any regular table which you want to deny `DELETE` according to your permissions and resources relations. that table has some special columns like `resource_id`, `owner_id` ?

Comment: Sorry! My bad. I have edited this.

Answer (score 2):

Check my fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9686e/1

As you can see in fiddle for `user_id=1` there is no permission assigned so `DELETE` statement delete nothing. But for `user_id=2` there is permission assigned and `DELETE` is successful.

```
DELETE my_table
FROM my_table  
INNER JOIN user_permission up
ON up.user_id = ?   <--- your user_id 
  AND up.permission_id = ? <---   your permission id
  AND up.access = 1  <--- your value which give permission to delete
WHERE my_table.id=2
;
```

You are welcome if any question. If you want to continue discussion you should provide your sqlfiddle with your real tables structure and some data.

Comment: Can we do that without JOIN?

Comment: I would say no. Or the solution will become much more complicated.